# Oracle Database installation on Fedora 14

Tags: database, oracle, fedora

I want to start learning **oracle database**(I have **FEDORA 14 (64 BIT)**), So what I will need to setup oracle database development environment. Please can anyone guide me? Basically I need a database server and a simple client ONLY FOR LEARNING. I went to the oracle website but there was a 2GB setup, so I thought to be advised by experts before downloading it.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oracle Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html) is the one you want. Free to use and good for learning. There's an 11gR2 version in beta. I'd expect that to go to full release in the next month. If you can't wait, then go with the 10gR2 one. No sense in mucking around with a Beta edition when you are new.

Install guide for linux is (currently) [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/install.102/b25144/toc.htm)

---

On 64bit Linux, I'd go for the Beta version of Express Edition (11g) which is only available in 64 bit (except the Windows version is 32 bit).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for such a composed answer. But I have 64 bit version of fedora, and there is only 32 bit version of oracle 10g. Can you please guide for this problem as well?

Comment: @dj aqeel, I tried getting 10g XE to install on my Fedora 15 and never could get it to work. I ended up with 11gR2 without the XE addition (if you're looking to work in APEX you can always just install it separate) and it went in just fine.